# «Житёнка» — уменьшительное от чего?

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Пейоративное *житёнка* не могло быть образовано от слова *жизнь*; от *житьё* — тоже крайне сомнительно. Вдобавок есть еще *житуха*, что наводит на мысль о существительном женского рода наподобие *жита*, *житка* или, может быть, *жить* (3-го склонения). Есть ли где-то следы такого слова?

Comment: @Artemix отчего же "житьё" не самостоятельное? а "житуха" тоже должна была откуда-то взяться.

Comment: Может это не уменьшительное, а образование от причастия/прилагательного, как сгущённое - сгущёнка, варёная - варёнка, плетёный - плетёнка?

Comment: @YellowSky а что в таком случае бывает "житёное"?

Comment: от житьё, очевидно

Comment: Зачем обязательно "житёное", может от "(про-)житое".

Comment: @YellowSky все упирается в то, что так оно не образуется. Меня тут, однако, посетила мысль: что, если все-таки "жизнь" породила "жизёнку" с последующей заменой по какой-нибудь аналогии?

Comment: «жизнь» - «жисть» - «жистянка», что под влиянием «житья» могло дать и «житенку». 

Кроме того, есть старое диалектное слово [«житенка» в значении житница](http://pki.botik.ru/books/pezanprob-dkl-11.pdf), оно в принципе могло быть переосмысленно в «жизнь».

Comment: @J-mster "житенка" — она *жИтенка*, как я понял. опять же, в такую вольность развития, как "житёнка" от "жистянки", мне не верится.

Comment: Согласен, оба варианта притянуты за уши. Но я не думаю, что там происходило какое-то длительное развитие, а неологизмы бывают довольно случайными. Представьте, что вам по ходу разговора понадобилось емкое словечко со значением  «мелкая, никчемная жизнь». Произносимых вариантов не так уж и много.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: could you please provide a usage sample (and a source, if possible)? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможно, что слово происходит не от *жизнь*, а от диалектного *житка* в значении *жила*.

> **[ЖИТКА](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/2822/%D0%96%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%9A%D0%90)** — Тянуть (вытягивать) [всю] житку из кого. Брян. То же, что
>   тянуть жилы (ЖИЛА).  *Большой словарь русских поговорок  — М: Олма Медиа Групп В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина 2007*
>
> **ТЯНУТЬ ЖИЛЫ** из кого. ВЫТЯНУТЬ ЖИЛЫ из кого. Разг. Предосуд. Изнурять,
>   изматывать кого-либо тяжёлой, непосильной работой, непомерными
>   требованиями, придирками. [Краснов:] Пожалейте вы меня: ведь вы из
>   меня жилы тянете (А. Островский. Грех да беда на кого не живёт).
>
> *Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008.*

Видимо, диалектный вариант *тянуть житку* переосмыслился как *жить тяжёлой жизнью* из-за схожести слов *житка* и *жизнь*. От *житка* легко образуется - *житуха*, *житёнка* и т.д. В пользу этого говорят и словосочетания типа *тянуть житуху*, довольно распространённые в разговорной речи.